# Nesting template in Angular 1 for tree view

Tags: angularjs, nested

I'm building a tree view in angular.

It is supposed to look like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Od7QTq2bGMeZr4vWg23T?p=preview

Nice, and pretty.

However, when I change my nested list from:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html" class="tree">





  <ul>
   <li>
      <div class="person">
         Simon
         <p></p>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div class="person">
               Walter
            </div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <div class="person">
                     Charles
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div class="person">
                     Dick
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div class="person">
                     Sarah
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="person">
               Edwin
            </div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <div class="person">
                     Edwin
                  </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div class="person">
                     Edwin
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <div class="person">
                           Edwin
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="person">
                           Edwin
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <div class="person">
                           Edwin
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div class="person">
                     Edwin
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="person">
               Hap
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

    </script>


    <div ng-controller="TreeController" >
      <div ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" class="tree"></div>
  </div>
```

To a nested template that I think is close to what I need, my template goes bizurk.

Here's what I've written.
Link to Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TQLYtAwDGmdK9EC5DVk9?p=preview[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TQLYtAwDGmdK9EC5DVk9?p=preview)

```
   <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html" >




      <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="person">
            Simon
            <p></p>
          </div>
           <!-- Not supposed to be a div!? -->
          <div ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </script>
```

It looks like my tree_item_render.html is being inserted as a div.  Messing up the list structure.  How can I remove that div to get my tree back? :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home these help i change your code to this, and here is the plnkr url
[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/U4DEHjMlZzeeAx5kIGRa?p=preview)

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="person">
        {{data.name}}
        <button ng-click="add(data)">Add Child</button>
          <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete Ancestors</button>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" class="tree">
      <ui>
    </li>
  </ul>

</script>


<div ng-controller="TreeController" class="tree">
  <div ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" class="tree"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the element form of this directive shown in the official doc?

```
<ng-include
    src="string"
    [onload="string"]
    [autoscroll="string"]>
    ...
</ng-include>
```